# Why does this Angular service return null value?

Tags: angular

Because of this service returning a null value, it can not push the value on the array. So i have to manually refresh the page of it to be display.
It means the back works but not the front.

```
addProduit(form: Formulaire): Observable<Produit>  {
    console.log("3: " + form);
    return this.http.post<Produit>(this.API_SERVER + '/produits',
      form,
      httpOptions
    ).pipe(
        tap({
          next: x => { console.log(x.formulaireJSON.id); },
          error: err => { console.error(err) },
          complete: () => { console.log('create Produit') }
    }));
  }
```

```
onSubmit(form: Formulaire) {
    if (!form) { return; }
    console.log("1: " + form);
    this.produitService.addProduit(form)
      .subscribe(produit => {
        this.produits.push(produit);
        console.log("2: " + produit);
      });
  }
```

form come from a formBuilder value. `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(produitForm.value)"`

```
export interface Produit {
    id: number;
    formulaireJSON: Formulaire;
}
export interface Formulaire {
    id: number;
    name: String;
    formulaire: String[];
}
```

There is a value in log 1: and 3: but not in 2:. The error appeared in next: x. `ERROR TypeError: x is null`

The JSON created is correct as it is added correctly in the database.

Where did I make a mistake? I did something very similar in the same project and it is working fine.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT to give the elements of answers, thanks to Michael D. :

What I did not understood was that the value return was coming from the back. I thought it was direct front to front. I thought the back was working fine, because I had implement the status for the request.

So I just had to add the return value for the request POST.

Comment: looking at the [docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) do you mean to do `tap(x  => {...`?

Comment: In the network tab do you see response returned by the API?

Comment: I want this part to work `... .subscribe(produit => { this.produits.push(produit); ...`, so if `tap({next: x => ...` works, everything should work i believe

Comment: Yes the back is working fine, i see the response and when I refresh the page the GET request works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things to consider.

1. Always define a type (atleast `any`) when you're trying to access it's properties using dot notation.

```js
tap({
  next: (x: Produit) => { console.log(x.formulaireJSON.id); },
  error: err => { console.error(err) },
  complete: () => { console.log('create Produit') }
})
```

2. The order of console logs could be 1, 3 and 2. Because the 2<sup>nd</sup> console log is inside the subscription callback and it *could* be triggered after the 3<sup>rd</sup> log.
3. If you were to add new elements to array using `.push()` method, Angular change detection mechanism won't be triggered since the underlying reference of the variable containing the object hasn't been adjusted. For that you could use destructing instead.

```js
subscribe((produit: Produit) => {
  this.produits = [...this.produits, produit];
  console.log("2: " + produit);
})
```

Comment: the problem is that x is `null`, so the type is not important. The order of console logs is not important, it was just for visibility. I tried your push method but the error stays the same.

Comment: If the `x` is `null`, then the issue is with the back end sending wrong response to the front end. Try if you could replicate the HTTP request in Postman with the same payload and options.

Comment: I'm so stupid, I thought the value return was direct front to front. Thanks!